# Printing a itext 7 pdf document (ideally via system.drawing.printing)

Tags: printing, itext, itext7

I developped a wrapper for itext7.
Everything works fine and I managed to do everything I wanted to.

Except of the most important thing: After creating the PDF it should be printed silently (in the background) without showing a printer dialog.

And it should not only be printed... I have to define some settings, such as printer name (where it has to be printed), whether color- or bw-printing, duplex or simplex and (if possible) the paper tray....

All these settings can be made within the PrinterSettings-Class of System.Drawing.Printing... But is there ANY possibility to print the itext-created PDF with this printing class????

Please help me.

Thank you!

Regards, Benni

Comment: I use Pdfium to print silently. See https://github.com/pvginkel/PdfiumViewer.

Comment: I will try this and bring feedback here....